# How to change slice of interface to slice of struct

Tags: go, struct, interface, slice

How to set slice of interface to slice of struct?

I define interface

```
type IFoo interface{
  //something methods
}
```

I define struct

```
type Foo struct{
  Id int `json:"Id"`
  //somethig fields
}
```

I create factory of structs and I want change IFoo slice to slice of concrette struct type

```
func FooFactory (p *[]IFoo) {
  *p = *(*[]IFoo)(unsafe.Pointer(&[]Foo{})
  //here I try something like unsafe.Pointer, reflect.SliceHeader but nothing does not works
}
```

and then I want to use result for Unmarshal json:

```
func main() {
  var o []IFoo
  FooFactory(&o)
  j := []byte(`[{"Id":1}, {"Id":2}]`)
  json.Unmarshal (j, &o)
  fmt.Println(o)
}
```

I get [map[Id:1] map[Id:2]]
But I want to get [{1} {2}]

If I define var o as []Foo I get expected result but I can't use concrete struct type as abstraction.

How to do? Thanks and sory for my bad english.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is not possible with `[]IFoo` and `encoding/json` because the `json` package won't look "further" than `IFoo` to try to figure out the element type of the slice. What you could do is use `*interface{}` as the argument to `FooFactory` and then simply set that as `*p = &[]Foo{}` and then passing `o`, without the `&` to `Unmarshal`.

Comment: ... that said, without knowing *why* you're doing what you're doing the way you're doing it, this looks like a very bad idea and I would recommend you rethink and redesign.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks. I want create an abstract factory to pass it fo some complex functions in loop. I need more than some hunders of different factories and I don`t want copy/paste for identical hundres rows of code for each type struct. But I want strong types nor "interface{}" at same time.

Comment: I understand than I can unmarshal data directly in factory code but I don't want "dirty" factory )

Comment: You want to use strong types and you don't want to dirty your factory, that's fine, just keep in mind, as I've already said, `encoding/json` doesn't work the way *you want*. Either write your own unmarshaler or scale down your wants.

Comment: Thank you. I keep in mind )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

https://play.golang.org/p/syNVY0KTtM2

Thank you all for assistance